# confused about function as instance of Functor in haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

The type of fmap in Functor is:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

it looks like ,first apply function (a -> b) to the parameter of f a to create a result of type b, then apply f to it, and result is f b

using `Maybe a` for example:

```
 fmap show (Just 1)
 result is : Just "1"
```

same as saying:

```
Just (show 1)
```

but when `(->)` is used as a Functor (in `Control.Monad.Instances`)

```
import Control.Monad.Instances
(fmap show Just) 1
result is : "Just 1"
```

that is, `Just` is applied first, then `show` is applied. In another example ,result is same:

```
 fmap (*3) (+100) 1
 result is 303
```

why not `*3` first, then `+100`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> the type of fmap in Functor is:
>
> ```
> fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> ```
>
> it looks like ,first apply function (a -> b) to the parameter of f a
>   to create a result of type b, then apply f to it, and result is f b

That is the type of `fmap`, but your interpretation of what that type means is wrong.

You seem to assume that `f a` has one parameter, and that that parameter has type `a`.

Consider `xs :: [a]`:

- Perhaps `xs = []`.
- Perhaps `xs = [x1]`.
- Perhaps `xs = [x1, x2]`.
- ...

The *type* `f a` is a functor `f` with a single type parameter `a`. But *values* of type `f a` do not necessarily take the form `F x`, as you can see from the first and third cases above.

Now consider `fmap f xs`:

- Perhaps `fmap f xs = []`.
- Perhaps `fmap f xs = [f x1]`.
- Perhaps `fmap f xs = [f x1, f x2]`.
- ...

We don't necessarily apply `f` at all (first case)! Or we might apply it more than once (third case).

What we do is replace the things of type `a`, with things of type `b`. But we leave the larger structure intact --- no new elements added, no elements removed, their order is left unchanged.

---

Now let's think about the functor `(c ->)`. (Remember, a functor takes one type parameter only, so the input to `(->)` is fixed.)

Does a `c -> a` even contain an `a`? It might not contain any `a`s at all, but it can somehow magic one out of thin air when we give it a `c`. But the result from `fmap` has type `c -> b`: we only have to provide a `b` out of that when we're presented with a `c`.

So we can say `fmap f x = \y -> f (x y)`.

In this case, we're applying `f` on demand --- every time the function we return gets applied, `f` gets applied as well.

Comment: yes, your answer is great! I made a big mistake. thank you very much.

Comment: I confuse "type parameter" with a concrete parameter

Answer (score 34):

The `fmap` instance for `(->) r` (i.e. functions) is literally just composition. From [the source itself](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Instances.html):

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

So, in your example, we can just replace `fmap` with `(.)`, and do some transformations

```
fmap (*3) (+100) 1 => 
(.) (*3) (+100) 1  =>
(*3) . (+100) $ 1  => -- put (.) infix
(*3) (1 + 100)     => -- apply (+100)
(1 + 100) * 3         -- apply (*3)
```

That is, `fmap` for functions composes them right to left (exactly the same as `(.)`, which is sensible because it is `(.)`).

To look at it another way (for (double) confirmation!), we can use the type signature:

```
-- general fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

-- specialised to the function functor (I've removed the last pair of brackets)
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
```

So first the value of type `r` (the third argument) needs to be transformed into a value of type `a` (by the `r -> a` function), so that the `a -> b` function can transform it into a value of type `b` (the result).

Comment: yes, fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b ,this explains much,thank you

Comment: The link was broken. It is now http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-818

Answer (score 21):

It *needs* to be defined that way to make the types work out. As you pointed out, the type of `fmap` is:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Let's consider the case when the functor `f` is `((->) c)`

(**Note:** we'd actually like to write this as `(c ->)`, i.e. functions from `c`, but Haskell doesn't allow us to do this.)

Then `f a` is actually `((->) c a)`, which is equivalent to `(c -> a)`, and similarly for `f b`, so we have:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> (c -> b)
```

i.e. we need to take two functions:

- `f :: a -> b`
- `g :: c -> a`

and construct a new function

- `h :: c -> b`

But there's only one way to do that: you have to apply `g` first to get something of type `a`, and then apply `f` to get something of type `b`, which means that you *have* to define

```
instance Functor ((->) c) where
    fmap f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

or, more succinctly,

```
instance Functor ((->) c) where
    fmap = (.)
```

Answer (score 6):

`fmap` for `(->)` is defined like `fmap = (.)`. 
So, `(fmap f g) x`  is `(f . g) x` is `f (g x)`. In your case `(*3) ((+100) 1)`, which equals `3 * (100 + 1)` which results in `303`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to form a function type, you need 2 kind parameters for (->), that is the single input argument type and the return type.

A Functor can only take 1 type parameter, so you have to nail down the input argument type(since it's the first one from left to right), which makes the return type of the function to be the type parameter of the Functor.

So for function (the Functor) a->b, you need to give fmap a function ff of type b->xxx other than a->xxx to work, and that means the function ff can only be applied after a->b is apply.