# Why does using fmap's infix synonym <$> return a different type for this expression?

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> :t (+2) <$> Just 2
(+2) <$> Just 2 :: Num b => Maybe b


Prelude> :t fmap (+2) Just 2
fmap (+2) Just 2 :: (Num (Maybe t), Num t) => Maybe t
```

However if I add brackets around the Maybe type I get the expected same result:

```
Prelude> :t fmap (+2) (Just 2)
fmap (+2) (Just 2) :: Num b => Maybe b
```

So my question is why - is it significance of the Maybe data constructor or something else?

Comment: You're missing parenthesis in your second example. Try `:t fmap (+2) (Just 2)`

Comment: Parentheses are required because that's how haskell is parsed. It has nothing to do with the maybe type.

Comment: Note that what is happening is that `(+2)` and `Just` are functions with types `Num a => a -> a` and `b -> Maybe b`, the `fmap` is using the [`Functor` instance of `->`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294272/confused-about-function-as-instance-of-functor-in-haskell), now by the functor instance we have `fmap f g = \y -> f (g y)` in our case `f = (+2)` and `g = Just`, so`fmap (+2) Just = \y -> (+2) (Just y)` Now you apply this to `2` and you get `(+2) (Just 2)`. Which explains the `Num (Maybe t)` constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infix operators always have lower priority than function application, so `(+2) <$> Just 2` is the same as `(+2) <$> (Just 2)` and therefore `(<$>) (+2) (Just 2)`. If you use `fmap` as an infix operator:

```
(+2) `fmap` Just 2
```

you'll get the same result.