# How can fmap be used with a data constructor?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm trying to understand some haskell code.

This makes sense.

```
Prelude> fmap (+1) (Just 1)
Just 2
```

This also makes sense.

```
Prelude> (fmap.fmap) (+1) (Just [1])
Just [2]
```

But I don't understand how this works.

```
Prelude> (fmap.fmap) (+1) Just 1
Just 2
```

I've tried working the parts out. It seems to me that this is what's happening.

```
(fmap (fmap (+1)) Just) 1
```

I tried typing the subexpressions.

This makes sense.

```
Prelude> :t fmap (+1)
fmap (+1) :: (Functor f, Num b) => f b -> f b
```

This still makes sense.

```
Prelude> :t fmap (fmap (+1))
fmap (fmap (+1)) :: (Functor f, Functor f1, Num b) =>
    f (f1 b) -> f (f1 b)
```

But I don't understand this.

```
Prelude> :t fmap (fmap (+1)) Just
fmap (fmap (+1)) Just :: Num b => b -> Maybe b
```

How did a function with type

```
(Functor f, Functor f1, Num b) => f (f1 b) -> f (f1 b)
```

after applying `Just` which has type:

```
a -> Maybe a
```

result in this type?

```
Num b => b -> Maybe b
```

The question [confused about function as instance of Functor in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294272/confused-about-function-as-instance-of-functor-in-haskell) might have something to do with this, but I still am confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You write `Just 1` instead of `(Just 1)` so as a result, these are two separate parameters. We can now rewrite it in a more canonical form, like:

```
   (fmap . fmap) (+1) Just 1
-> (\x -> fmap (fmap x)) (+1) Just 1
-> ((fmap (fmap (+1)) Just) 1
```

So now we can analyze the types:

```
fmap1 :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap2 :: Functor g => (c -> d) -> g c -> g d
(+1) :: Num h => h -> h
Just :: i -> Maybe i
1 :: Num j => j
```

Where `fmapi` is the *i*-th `fmap` in the expression (if we read it left-to-right). If we know perform some analysis, we see that since we use `fmap (+1)`, we know that `c ~ d ~ h`:

```
fmap1 :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap2 :: Functor g => (h -> h) -> g h -> g h
(+1) :: Num h => h -> h
Just :: i -> Maybe i
1 :: Num j => j
```

We then see that the first `fmap` (`fmap1`) is called with `fmap (+1) :: Functor g => g h -> g h` as first argument, and `Just :: i -> Maybe i` as second argument. So if we further perform type analysis we get: `(a -> b) ~ g h -> g h`, so `a ~ b ~ g h`, and we know that `f (g h) ~ i -> Maybe i`, so that means that `f (g h) ~ (->) i (Maybe i)` so `f ~ (->) i` and `g ~ Maybe`, `h ~ i`, furthermore `i ~ j`:

```
fmap1 :: (Maybe i -> Maybe i) -> (->) i (Maybe i) -> (->) i Maybe i
fmap2 :: (i -> i) -> Maybe i -> Maybe i
(+1) :: Num h => i -> i
Just :: i -> Maybe i
1 :: Num i => i
```

Now a crucial aspect here is that `(->) r` is a functor as well, indeed in the [`base-4.10.1.0` source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html) we see:

> ```
> instance Functor ((->) r) where
>     fmap = (.)
> ```

We can here see a function as a functor, and if we perform an `fmap` we "post process" the result. So it means that *after* we apply `Just`, we apply `fmap (+1)` to that result. So the first `fmap` is equivalent to `(.)` whereas the second one is the `fmap` over `Maybe`, so as a result we get:

```
   ((fmap (fmap (+1)) Just) 1
-> (((.) (fmap (+1)) Just) 1
-> ((\x -> (fmap (+1) (Just x)) 1
-> fmap (+1) (Just 1)
-> Just 2
```

So in short we use the `(fmap (+1))` as a *post processing* step, *after* we apply `Just` to `1`.

Comment: The part in the last code snippet, where you spelled it out that the first fmap is (.) made it so clear to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

What happened was `f` resolved to the functor `(->) a`, and `f1` to `Maybe`, since

```
Just :: (->) a (Maybe a)
```

So if we write the type of `fmap (fmap (+1))` with the above bindings we get:

```
fmap (fmap (+1)) :: Num b => (->) a (Maybe b) -> (->) a (Maybe b)
```

Rewriting `(->)` as an infix constructor we get:

```
fmap (fmap (+1)) :: Num b => (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe b)
```

Now we apply this to `Just :: a -> Maybe a` so we get

```
fmap (fmap (+1)) Just :: Num a => a -> Maybe a
```